# Big theorem to generate a sequence

Tags: calculus

How do you do: 
Construct a sequence $\{{x_{n}}\}^{\infty}_{n=0}$ such that

$n^{a} << x_{n} << n^{b}$ for all $a < 2$ and $b \geq 2$

Edit:

To clarify: $a$ and $b$ are real numbers quantified above. I'm completely confused, and do not know how to approach this.

Comment: This needs more details. What are $a,b$? What have you tried? Does this make sense for $n=0,1$?

Comment: What does $<<$ mean ?

Comment: << and >> need to be defined.

Comment: Does $x_n << n^b$ stand for $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{n^b} = 0?$$

Comment: Sorry I assumed this notation was universal. It means much larger than or much smaller than asymptotically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that
the inequalities are to hold
for all large enough $n$.

A key for this
is to know that,
for any $c > 0$,
$\ln(x) < x^c$
for all large enough $x$.

If $x_n = \dfrac{n^2}{\ln(n)}$,
then,
$x_n >> n^a$
for $a < 2$
and
$x_n
\lt\lt n^2
\le n^b$
for $b \ge 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$x_n=\frac {n^{2}} {\ln (n+2)},n \geq 0$ works.

Comment: Same as mine, obviously independent, so upvoted.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks. I have upvoted your's.